# Spring boot restful API validation in layered architecture

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

Today i have a big discussion with one of our team member about validation of RESTful API input in `Controller` and `Service` layer and i feel it is a bad day for making bigger argument. So we have a spring boot microservice application with layered architecture

```
Controller --> Service --> Repository
```

**The argument is having the validation at each layer or just having the validation at `Controller` layer**, for example we have `Controller` with `POST` request and using [JSR-380](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation#jsr303) validation for input request body

**Controller :**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/", consumes = {"application/json"}, produces = {"application/json"})
public ResponseEntity<Detail> createConfig(

        @NotNull(message = "{error.message.config_detail}")
        @RequestBody @Validated Config config) {

    return new ResponseEntity<>(configService.create(config.getConfigId(), config.getTaskId()), HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
```

**Config :** Request Body

```
public class Config {

@ApiModelProperty(name = "config_id", example = "1", required = true)
@NotNull(message = "{error.message.config_id}")
private Long configId;

@ApiModelProperty(name = "task_id", example = "11", required = true)
@NotNull(message = "{error.message.task_id}")
@Min(value = 0, message = "{error.message.task_id}")
@Max(value = 9999, message = "{error.message.task_id}")
private Integer taskId;

// bunch of addition fields with validations 

 }
```

If the validation success then calling the `Service` method with some properties from `Config`

**Service :**

```
public Detail create(@Valid @NotNull Long configId, @NotNull Integer taskId) {

   // some business logic to convert to entity and saving to database

    return repository.save(entity));
}
```

So if we see the above code, same validation is done at `Controller` and `Service`, So i argued that there is no need of validating in `Service` layer, perform the validation at controller layer and if input is wrong then throw `400` or `500` to user. **But another person in team also suggest having validation in each block for whatever is used in the block, so that individual piece of code is safe (focusing on the unit instead of the integration path).**

I know i might be wrong in this case, but still not able to understand the validation at each layer,(null check  i agree) so it is recommended approach having validation at each level

```
Controller --> validation call service

Service ---> validation and call business 

Business ---> validation and call repository

Repository --> save
```

**But what is the prefered way of validation ?** according to me if `Controller` input is valid call `Service` and perform business logic and call `Repository`. correct me if i'm wrong so that i can follow the recommended pattern

Answer (score 1):

You are right : the validation should be placed in controller, if possible. And it's make no sense in my opinion to validate the data more then 1 time.
See also DRY principle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Answer (score 1):

It is situational. Some validation needs to be performed in the service layer. Say, you will need to change a state of an object, but only if certain conditions are met etc.
A part from that, as a rule of thumb i follow these guidelines: 
If your services are publicly exposed to other services via RMI, then service layer validation is mandatory, if not go with controller level validation.

Comment: If data isn't valid then why need to call the service and validate there?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using the services and / or repositories as libraries in other projects, too, it does not make sense to do the validation multiple times.
If the controllers are the only classes accessing the additional layers there is no need for additional validation as you and your controller are the only one to access the Spring beans. You and the controller are in control of accessing the services with valid parameters.

Doing several validations has the disadvantage of writing more complex services - including unit tests.
It is slower.
Changing the validation will take longer as multiple layers have to be changed - including unit tests.
The validations on several layers can and will differ in a matter of time.

The preferred way is to do the validation once in (or even before) the controller and writing integration tests to ensure its functionality.